# (MFC) How can a parent class receive a control's messages if the control is a private member?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

Let's say my main class has a private member that is a class derived from a CTreeView control.  How can I handle the messages from this tree view control on the main class itself?

This is similar to the MDI base application that Visual Studios builds for you, where you have two dockable tree view controls named CClassView and CFileView and each has a private member that's derived from CTreeView.

Can I pass the message from the child member control CViewTree to my CFileView class with like this?

```
void CViewTree::OnTvnSelchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, 0, (LPARAM)pNMHDR);
}
```

This code throws an exception, but if this does work, how would I handle the TVN_SELCHANGED message in the parent class?

Edit:
So I've tried the following suggestions but haven't had much luck with either one.

```
//First try, in the parent .h file:
afx_msg BOOL OnSelChange(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);

//In the .cpp file:
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(TVN_SELCHANGED, OnSelChange)

//and

BOOL ParentClass::OnSelChange(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
     AfxMessageBox(L"in handler");
     Return TRUE;
}
```

Second try:

```
//in the parent .h file:
afx_msg void OnSelChange(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);

//In the .cpp file:
ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGED, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, OnSelChange)

//and
void  ParentClass::OnSelChange(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
     AfxMessageBox(L"in handler");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this, you have less code reusability as you have a tight coupling between the view and the parent. If you want to reuse the selection logic, you can extract it out into a separate class like the [DRAWCLI sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t94971d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) does.

TVN_SELCHANGED is already sent to the parent. However MFC's [message reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) routes the notification to the child window's message map when ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT is present in the child.

If you want the parent to have a say in the message processing as well, you can change ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT to ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX and return FALSE in the reflected message handler.

You will get a WM_NOTIFY at the parent so the way you handle the notification is to add [a ON_NOTIFY macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/749htf6k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to the parent of the tree view like you normally do for a tree control on a dialog. The view's id is likely AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST if you haven't specified one.

Comment: Excellent write-up. Many people try to "cook up" features that MFC already provides.

Comment: To be honest I don't want to do it this way.  I want to do it the "correct" way.  I've tried handling TVN_SELCHANGED in the parent, but it wasn't working.  Of course it's likely I'm doing it wrong.  Can you give me an example how you would handle this message in the parent?

Comment: You will get a WM_NOTIFY at the parent so what you do is to add a ON_NOTIFY macro to the parent of the tree view like you normally do for a tree control on a dialog. The view's id is likely AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST if you haven't specified one.

Comment: @subject_x You should look into the two links included in the answer. They describe message reflection and how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I read it through the answer and didn't even notice the links.

Comment: I tried to follow the logic for the DrawCLi example and it confuses me even more.  There is no use of ON_NOTIFY_RELFECT or EX in any of the classes.  All I would like to do is

Comment: DrawCLi is for separating your window class and business logic for better code reusability. If you won't ever reuse your old code (more work in the long run), skip this part.

Comment: @Nik, sorry about the unfinished comment above. I tried to follow the logic for the DrawCLi example and it confuses me even more, I'm only a beginner with MFC.  There is no use of ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT or EX in any of the classes that I could compare with.  With the second link, I think I'm suppose to declare my message map like ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(TVN_SELCHANGED, OnSelChanged) in the parent.  In my OnSelChanged is where I'm suppose to put my logic.  I tried just displaying a message box in that method, but it's not trapping the message.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sheng I will try your suggestion of using ON_NOTIFY with the AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST id.

Comment: Well, the answer to "what am I doing wrong?" is "no idea." I can't see your code. If you want to see an example of reflection in action, check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra

Comment: My code is very basic, but I'll throw it up in the initial question.

Comment: @Sheng I'm trying to follow what you said about changing ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT to ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX on the child class, but I didn't see either defined in the .cpp or as an option in the Class Wizard.  I went ahead and try adding it manually in the child with the "Second Try" solution for my parent class, but it's still not displaying a message box.

Comment: There is no wizard support for ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX, you need to change the ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT macro or add a new one manually to the view class. Also you need to verify the ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT function's signature is afx_msg BOOL (NMHDR * pNotifyStruct , LRESULT* result) and return FALSE for the reflection so the message got routed back to the parent.

Comment: ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT expects a handler that returns void.  Changing it to BOOL throws error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'BOOL (__thiscall CViewTree::* )(NMHDR *,LRESULT *)' to 'void (__thiscall CCmdTarget:

Comment: @Sheng When I use ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX instead, it rebuilds fine, but my messagebox is still not displaying, meaning my handler in the parent is not being triggered.  The handler in the child is being called though.  Also I am returning FALSE in that handler.

Comment: Would the fact that the parent class isn't a derived class of the treeview control class be the problem?  I'm just thinking that this shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: 1 are you sure your parent class has a working message map (e.g. is WM_PAINT called?) 2 in InitUpdate check if your view has another child id 3 are you sure the parent is actually the direct parent, e.g. there is no CSpliiterWnd or MDI child frame in the middle?

Comment: Thanks for working with me this entire time.  I really appreciate your help and knowledge.  I used VS 2010 to generate this example so I'm not 100% sure how the parent/child relationship defined.  Instead of pasting all the code here, you may have a better understand by creating a skeleton MDI app in Visual studio.  It's a standard MDI w/ VS style.  It'll generate two dockable trees CFileView and CClassView along with a main view.  There's no splitter window.  I'm trying to have CFileView handle it's tree control's messages.

Comment: Then your control ID in the macro needs to be changed to the one you passed in m_wndFileView.Create

Comment: How do you determine that ID?  the creation code is if (!m_wndFileView.Create(dwViewStyle, rectDummy, this, 4)).  If I'm reading the MSDN correctly on the Create method, the ID is the 4 right?

Comment: that worked Sheng!!!!!  I didn't have to do anything to the child class as far as handling the TVN_SELCHANGED.  I'll post my answer that you've helped me with.

Answer (score 3):

Sheng was able to figure out my problem, which looking back now was quite trivial.  Maybe this will help others who might have the same question.

In the MDI w/ visual studio style program that I generated from Visual Studio 2010, the CFileView has a child member instance of CViewTree.  CViewTree was derived from CTreeCtrl.

By default, MFC is already passing the messages up the child-to-parent chain.  The answer is determining the control ID to get notification messages from in your parent class.

So, first things first, we need to know the ID of the tree control.  In the OnCreate method of CFileView, you can see this code:

```
if (!m_wndFileView.Create(dwViewStyle, rectDummy, this, 4))
```

MSDN has the following for the Create method:

```
virtual BOOL Create(
   DWORD dwStyle,
   const RECT& rect,
   CWnd* pParentWnd,
   UINT nID 
);
```

In my example, the id is 4.  Now in the parent (CFileView in this case), just create your ON_NOTIFY macro as such:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFileView, CDockablePane)  //precreated for you
    ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGED, 4, OnSelChanged)  //you create this
END_MESSAGE_MAP()  //precreated for you
```

I had to type the line above by hand because the class wizard or message property for the parent didn't have a =TVN_SELCHANGED message.  Next, make sure your handler method OnSelChanged is declared in the CFileView.h file as:

```
afx_msg void OnSelChanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
```

Now I'm able to handle the TVN_SELCHANGED message like this (back in the CFileView.cpp):

```
void CFileView::OnSelChanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    HTREEITEM item = m_wndFileView.GetSelectedItem();
    AfxMessageBox(m_wndFileView.GetItemText(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the described case if you want to notify parent CFileView from control CViewTree with WM_NOTIFY TVN_SELCHANGED message, you should do it in virtual OnNotify function, not using message map. If OnNotify doesn't met correct handler, message would go to parent CMainFrame, and there you can use message map.

```
BOOL CFileView::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
   if (nmHdr->idFrom != 4)
      return CDockablePane::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);
   if (nmHdr->code == TVN_SELCHANGED)
   {
      OnItemsSelChanged((NMHDR*)lParam, pResult);
      return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```